# Hadoop Hypercube

Tags: hadoop, olap, apache-pig, hypertable, hypercube

Hey,
i am starting a hadoop based hypercube with a flexible number of dimensions.
Does anybody know any existing approaches for this?

I just found [PigOLAPSketch](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigOLAPSketch), but there is no code to use it.

Another approach is [Zohmg](http://www.zohmg.com/) from lastfm, which uses hbase, but seems to be very dead.

I think i will start a pig solution, maybe you have some advices?

Answer (score 0):

This would be very cool/useful. OpenTSDB is an HBase time-series database that might be interesting to look at, they have a clever approach to secondary indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at gpu based database https://www.kinetica.com/
but this is not open source, requires separate appliances and movement of data from Hadoop to Kinetica infrastructure.